# Autoloading Classes in Plugins

Tags: php, plugin-development, customization, directory, autoloading

In a custom WordPress plugin I have a folder `/classes` with about 20 classes. Classes sometimes change, come and go. I want all those classes from the folder to be loaded automatically.

No my idea was to load those files by a simple loop require:

```
foreach (scandir(dirname(__FILE__)."/classes/") as $filename) {
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $filename;
    if (is_file($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
}
```

However this does not work because there are subclasses loaded before superclasses and I get a fatal error.

PHP usually solves this problem with the [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function.

However this seems not to work if used in multiple plugins. Has anybody found a good solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Have you considered using the composer autoloader? I have multiple plugins each with their own composer generated autoloaders, and they work just fine

Comment: Not yet thats a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Composer Autoloader as suggested in the comments is the best way to do it. Just use composers classmap feature:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["classes/"]
}
```